# brower/tab close show confirmation like "Exit" and "cancel"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Show Confirmation Box when user leaving tab/ or Browser close like "continue" or "exit".

I tried window.onUnload event also but not working.

But this event called only once. and second time round it does not execute the function

```js
var areYouReallySure = false;
var internalLink = false;
var allowPrompt = true;

function areYouSure() {
  if (allowPrompt) {
    if (!areYouReallySure && !internalLink && true) {
      areYouReallySure = true;
      var ConfMsg = "click Cancel"
      return ConfMsg;
    }
  } else {
    allowPrompt = true;
  }
  //}
}
//var allowPrompt = true;
window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
```

How to code for reload and cancel button ,which come on prompt?

Comment: Are you sure the function isn't getting _called_ again? Your code within `areYouSure` will prevent it _returning_ `ConfMessage` a second time.

Comment: yes @John. second time its not execute again, only go to onbeforeunload line.

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` function will call when you try to close the tab not on the button click.

In your code as you are using this `areYouReallySure` variable. So first is `false` so it is working but after you have set as `true` inside of if condition. That's why it is not working because in second time is not return anything.

```
window.onbeforeunload = funcRef
```

- **funcRef** is a reference to a function or a function expression.
- The function should assign a string value to the returnValue property of the Event object and return the same string.

The [`WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event handler property contains the code executed when the `beforeunload` is sent. This event fires when a window is about to unload its resources. The document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

---

**CODE SNIPPET**

```js
//This function will call on before close tab
function areYouSure() {
  return "You have made changes, are you sure you would like to navigate away from the page?"
}

window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
```

Comment: How to code for reload and cancel button ,which come on prompt?

Comment: For reload you can use `location.reload()` and for cancel it will just close the prompt box. Can you more explain what exactly you need ?

Comment: on reload button click, i want call "logout button" event. on cancel button- no change on page. On reload button  i want to clear all session also logout the current user.